# Why does ASP.NET debugging process stop running on one laptop?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2019

So I'm working on a ASP.NET project with a friend.

The problem is that when I tested the project on my laptop, it worked fine. But the ASP.NET debugging process on my friend's laptop kept stopping at this one jquery onchange event. I tried on my laptop again and it still worked fine.

What is the explanation for this and is there a solution?

Comment: Are you using same browser in both lap?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had faced similar type of issue.Here is steps to follow:

1. Check Browsers should be updated or at least version should match with working laptop
2. Try using same browser on both laptop.
3. Disable cache and give it a shot
4. Check Console what error are you getting.

Comment: Thank you so much. I asked my friend to use the same browser and it worked fine. It really was just an issue with the browser she was using